# How do I save a bindingsource sort order but remove the sort?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I am sorting my binding source via the datagridview column header like so:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

    Dim p = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
    If DataGridView1.SortOrder = SortOrder.Descending Then

        BindingSource1.Sort = p + " DESC"

    ElseIf DataGridView1.SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
        BindingSource1.Sort = p + " ASC"

    End If
    ' The Sorted View converted to DataTable and then assigned to table object.
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is sort the bindingsource, remember the new sorted  order than clear the sort. If I don't clear the sort the state is always set to either ascending or descending which causes newley added rows to snap to order (which I don't want). Any ideas?

Comment: It doesnt generally work that way with DB objects.